# While loop should be appending closed parentheses to end of string but string not modified

Tags: javascript, string, while-loop, append, concatenation

I've written a function that takes a string containing parentheses, loops through the string and counts the number of open and closed parentheses using a for loop. A while loop is then supposed to loop over the string while the number of open parentheses is greater than the number of closed parentheses and append a closed parenthesis to the string. My example code :

```
function closeThoseParens(string) {
let openTicker = 0;
let closedTicker=0;
for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] === '(') {
        openTicker++;
        console.log(openTicker);
    } else if (string[i] === ')') {
        closedTicker++;
    }
}

while (openTicker > closedTicker){
    string += ")"
    closedTicker++;
    console.log(closedTicker);
}}
```

calling the function on:

```
let string = '((( )';
closeThoseParens(string)
```

Should result in a value for string of '((( )))'
However the value returned from the function seems to just be the input string. The tickers show the expected values when logged to the console.

I'm not sure what is happening here, there seems to be something wrong with the way I'm trying to append to the end of the string variable, but I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: You're not modifying the original string, you're modifying the local variable called `string`.  That's why you have to reassign the result of the addition back to `string` each iteration.  Instead of trying to mutate a parameter, it usually better to return a new parameter anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not modifying the original string, you're modifying the local variable called `string`.  That's why you have to reassign the result of the addition back to `string` each iteration.

If you're not familiar with the concept of passing by reference vs passing by value, you can skip this paragraph.  In JS, strings are passed by value.  What this effectively means is you're getting a copy of the string, so you can't modify the original value.  If JS passed strings by reference, you would be able to modify the original string and wouldn't have to return a new one.  (Disclaimer: This is very simplified, I'm trying to explain this in terms that those new to these concepts can hopefully understand.)

Instead of trying to mutate a parameter, it's usually better to return a new parameter anyways.  This is true even for objects where you can modify the original object (to an extent).  This is a paradigm of Functional programming that attempts to avoid difficult to understand (and debug) side effects.

To get this to work, you can do something like

```js
function closeThoseParens(string) {
  let openTicker = 0;
  let closedTicker=0;
  let closedParens = string;

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] === '(') {
      openTicker++;
      console.log(openTicker);
    } else if (string[i] === ')') {
      closedTicker++;
    }
  }

  while (openTicker > closedTicker){
    closedParens += ")"
    closedTicker++;
    console.log(closedTicker);
  }

  return closedParens;
}

console.log(closeThoseParens('((( )'));
```

Comment: This makes sense and it works! Thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.